# How to reassign a class method after calling another method?

Tags: python, methods, decorator

I am currently working on a Python project with a couple class methods that are each called tens of thousands of times. One of the issues with these methods is that they rely on data being populated via another method first, so I want to be able to raise an error if the functions are called prior to populating the data.

And before anyone asks, I opted to separate the data population stage from the class constructor. This is because the data population (and processing) is intensive and I want to manage it separately from the constructor.

### Simple (inefficient) implementation

A simple implementation of this might look like:

```py
class DataNotPopulatedError(Exception):
    ...


class Unblocker1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self._is_populated = False

    def populate_data(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self._is_populated = True

    # It will make sense later why this is its own method
    def _do_something(self):
        print("Data is:", self.data)

    def do_something(self):
        if not self._is_populated:
            raise DataNotPopulatedError

        return self._do_something()


unblocker1 = Unblocker1()

# Raise an error (We haven't populated the data yet)
unblocker1.do_something()

# Don't raise an error (We populated the data first)
unblocker1.populate_data([1,2,3])
unblocker1.do_something()
```

### My goal

Because the hypothetical `do_something()` method is called tens (or hundreds) of thousands of times, I would think those extra checks to make sure that the data has been populated would start to add up.

While I may be barking up the wrong tree, my first thoughts to improve the efficiency of thefunction were to dynamically re-assign the method after the data is populated. I.e., when first creating the class, the `do_something()` method would point to another function that only raises a `DataNotPopulatedError`. The `populate_data()` method would then both populate the data and also "unblock" `do_something()` by dynamically reassigning `do_something()` back to the function as written.

I figure the cleanest way to implement something like this would be using a decorator.

#### Hypothetical usage

I have no idea how to implement the technique described above, however, I did create a hypothetical usage with the inefficient method from before. Given the goal implementation, there might need to be two decorators--one for the blocked functions, and one to unblock them.

```py
import functools

def blocked2(attr, raises):
    def _blocked2(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Assumes `args[0]` is `self`
            # If `self.key` is False, raise `raises`, otherwise call `func()`
            if not getattr(args[0], attr):
                raise raises

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return _blocked2


class Unblocker2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self._is_populated = False

    def populate_data(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self._is_populated = True

    @blocked2("_is_populated", DataNotPopulatedError)
    def do_something(self):
        print("Data is:", self.data)
```

I've been having a hard time explaining what I am attempting to do, so I am open to other suggestions to accomplish a similar goal (and potentially better titles for the post). There is a decent chance I am taking the complete wrong approach here; that's just part of learning. If there is a better way of doing what I am trying to do, I am all ears!

Comment: Is the check for data population expensive operation? Bool check is not expensive even if called loads of times. Personally I would just do class read only property here.

Comment: Furthermore, what type of operation the `do_something` is? As in, is it independent on the size of the `data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do does not seem especially difficult. I suspect you are overcomplicating the task a bit. Assuming you are willing to respect your own private methods, you can do something like

```
class Unblocker2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    def populate_data(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.do_something = self._do_something_populated

    def do_something(self):
        raise DataNotPopulatedError('Data not populated yet')

    def _do_something_populated(self):
        print("Data is:", self.data)
```

Since methods are non-data descriptors, assigning a bound method to the instance attribute `do_something` will shadow the class attribute. That way, instances that have data populated can avoid making a check with the minimum of redundancy.

That being said, profile your code before going off and optimizing it. You'd be amazed at which parts take the longest.

Comment: Maybe for clarity call the actual methods something more descriptive, like `_do_something_error_not_populated` and `_do_something_really_populated`?

Comment: @tripleee. I've updated the private method. It's pretty clear as it is, IMO

Comment: Me? Overcomplicate something? Impossible. Thanks for the feedback! This was essentially what I had in mind, but I was trying to do it with decorators because I thought it'd be cool and elegant.

Comment: @Antyos. They are. It's funny how easily I can see overcomlication when someone else does it :)